# MATLAB: removing some of the elements of a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that looks like :

```
A =[
    1  5
    2 10
    3 12
    4 25
    5  8]
```

Let's assume that I want to remove the rows that contain elements that are larger than `10`. I have been trying to use a for loop and simply read the matrix and use

```
for ii = 1:5
   for jj = 2 
      if A(ii,jj) > 10
         A(ii,2) = [];
      end
   end
end
```

The problem is that, I keep receiving errors regarding the size of a matrix. As one row is deleted, the size of the matrix is reduced and I know that I have to set `size(A)=size(A)-1` but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By the way: If the size of the matrix may changes in one loop iteration you could count from the end to the beginning of the matrix to avoid the access of an element which doesn't exit. But this is only a general hint and not the solution for you problem cause I already saw that there is an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove a single element when using subscript notation, so your error is here:

```
A(i,2) = [];
```

You have two choices, either remove the entire row:

```
A(i,:) = [];
```

or else linearise your matrix and remove single elements (but then you won't be able to recover you original shape:

```
for ii = numel(A):-1:1
    if A(ii) > 10
        A(ii) = [];
    end
end
```

but using a loop for this is unnecessary and probably inefficient. You can do it using logical indexing like so:

```
A(any(A'>10),:) = [];
```

to remove the whole row or else to just remove single elements try:

```
A(A>10) = []
```

but then you'll see that you end up with a row vector (linearized) result

Comment: Well, that was a mistake in typing. I tried this, yet I get this error:
Attempted to access A(10); index out of bounds because numel(A)=9.

Comment: @elhmo yes that will happen in the loop. The loop is a bad way to go. I'll update the loop so it makes more sense though, basically it should be running from the bottom to the top so that you don't skip elements since deleting an element bumps all the elements after it higher up

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, quite similar to the one of @Dan. Basically this keeps what you want instead of removing what you don't want:

```
A(all(A<=10,2),:)
```